# Add a CSS class to a single element in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I am trying to add a class to an array element, which is a specific character, upon the keypress of that character. The expected outcome is that if the key "y" is pressed, the class "selected" will be added only to the "y" in the array, which will change it's color and strike a line through it.

I have a keypress event set up and I can add the class to the entire div where the array has been appended upon keypress, but I cannot figure out how to add the class to a single element in the array upon the keypress of that character.

---

#### My JS code:

```
var $arr = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ".split("");

$('#characters').append($arr);
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  var pressed = event.keyCode;
  var alreadyPressed = [];
  var pressedChar = String.fromCharCode(pressed);
  console.log(pressedChar, pressed);
  for (i = 0; i <= $arr.length; i++) {
    var arrCharacter = $arr[i];
    if((arrCharacter === pressedChar) && (jQuery.inArray(pressed, alreadyPressed) === -1)) { 
          $(this).addClass("selected");
            alreadyPressed.push(pressed); 
        } 
  }
})
```

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/minditorrey/1xjg9z24/) is also a Fiddle.

Comment: String arrays aren't DOM elements, so don't have style.  Where exactly are you **expecting to see** the change of colour and line?

Comment: How do you add a class to an array index?

Comment: That is my question, @epascarello. I have appended the array to the div with the id "characters"--so, my question is, how can I add a class to an individual element of that array, which is now being displayed?

Comment: You want to add it to the text in the div, not the array.

Comment: So, @freedomn-m, I am expecting to see the change where the array is displayed inside the div. I just don't know how to change a single element/character rather than all of them. Do I need to hand code the array into spans for each element of the array? Do I need to make a button for each character in the array?

Comment: @MindiTorrey I think you are misleading the term `array` here if i guess. I think you need to change the color of an character inside `div`. Well, you can separate those characters with individual elements like `span`. This way you can add class on desired span.

Comment: @MindiTorrey : There are quite a few things that can be improved in your code. For example, you don't need a `for`-loop at all to process your pressed key. Also, your `alreadyPressed` array isn't used the way you think it is. Anyway, check my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093495/add-a-css-class-to-a-single-element-in-an-array/36094029#36094029) for an optimised implementation of what you're going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $arr = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ".split("");
$.each($arr, function(index,elem){
    console.log(elem);
    $('#characters').append("<span id='"+elem+"'>"+elem+"</span>");
});

//$('#characters').append($arr);
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  var pressed = event.keyCode;
  var alreadyPressed = [];
  var pressedChar = String.fromCharCode(pressed);
  console.log(pressedChar, pressed);
  for (i = 0; i <= $arr.length; i++) {
    var arrCharacter = $arr[i];
    if((arrCharacter === pressedChar) && (jQuery.inArray(pressed, alreadyPressed) === -1)) { 
          $("#"+pressedChar).addClass("selected");
            alreadyPressed.push(pressed); 
        } 
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. This is what I was trying to get to. I could not figure out how to work the selector. Thank you so much!

Comment: You'd be better off using a `data-` attribute rather than `id` even if you keep the for loop. See this much improved answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36093732/2181514

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in a span, give them a unique key to look up the key, and use that key in a selector to select the element.

```js
var arr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split("");
var html = arr.reduce( function (str, txt) { return str +  '<span data-id="' + txt + '">' + txt + '</span>'  }, "");
$("#out").html(html);

$(window).on("keypress", function(evt) {
      var strChar = String.fromCharCode(evt.which).toLowerCase();
      $('span[data-id="' + strChar + '"]').addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.selected {
    color: green;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do :

1. Put all your letters in individual `<span>` elements
2. Add the selected class to the corresponding `<span>` element when pressing a letter key

Check out the demo below for an optimal implementation.

---

#### Demo

```js
var arr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split("");
var $characters = $('#characters');
var alreadyPressed = [];

$.each(arr, function(key, value){
    $characters.append("<span id='span" + value + "'>" + value + "</span>");
});

$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    var pressedChar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if($.inArray(pressedChar, arr) !== -1 && $.inArray(pressedChar, alreadyPressed) === -1) { 
        $("#span" + pressedChar).addClass("selected");
        alreadyPressed.push(pressedChar); 
    } 
});
```

```css
.container {
    color: gray;
}

#characters {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.selected {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

[id^=span] {
    padding-right: .4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Superfun Typing Game </h1>
    <p>To win, type every letter from a-z and every number from 0-9.</p>
    <div id="characters"></div>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zLm9ywu3/7/))

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

1. Only jQuery objects have method `.addClass()` and you try to call it from a string. You need to assign each letter as a class to a single element.
2. In your case .split() must have a space inside: `.split(" ")`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic here is a little flawed. It would be much simpler to append each character in its own `span` element so that it can be easily found when it's key is pressed. You also could also use a class to identify the `span` element on keypress, instead of having to maintain a separate array. This allows you to use the DOM directly to maintain the state, instead of having to keep track of that array with regards to what has and has not been pressed. Because of this you can easily tell when all keys have been pressed by comparing the total number of character spans to the number of those which have the `selected` class.

With all that in mind, try this:

```
var charArr = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'.split('');
var charHtml = '';
for (var i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
    charHtml += '<span class="char_' + charArr[i] + '">' + charArr[i] + '</span>';
}
$('#characters').append(charHtml);

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var $characters = $('#characters span');
    $characters.filter('.char_' + String.fromCharCode(e.which)).addClass('selected');    
    if ($characters.length == $characters.filter('.selected').length) {
        alert('All selected!');
    }
})
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1xjg9z24/3/)